# Gradle Properties for environment placeholders

Tags: gradle

I'm creating a build gradle project to ease deployment phase. My idea is to have a config folder with all needed config files in it. I want to fill these files with placeholders, for example, `${databaseName}`. The values that will be replaced during gradle script execution have to be loaded from properties files.

I want to have one properties file per environment, for example, `dev.properties`, `stage.properties`, `prod.properties`. The logic selection for that `*.propeties` have to be loaded by property command attribute, something like, `gradle myTask -Denv=dev`, in this way the placeholder will be loaded with `dev.properties` values.

What is the best choice on Gradle world to manage these needs?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout how ReplaceToken ant filter is working with the Copy task in Gradle. Have a look at https://discuss.gradle.org/t/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-file-while-it-is-in-flight-as-part-of-a-copy/17828/2 as an example

Comment: Not sure why this answer had votes. But it's pointing to a great source.